# Only change a ListViewItem's Checked state if the checkbox is clicked

Tags: .net, listview, listviewitem

By default, double-clicking a ListViewItem toggles its Checked state.  I only want the Checked state to be changed by clicking an the item's checkbox or pressing the space bar while an item is highlighted.  Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution involves 3 events and one state variable of type bool:

```
private bool inhibitAutoCheck;

private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    inhibitAutoCheck = true;
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    inhibitAutoCheck = false;
}

private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    if (inhibitAutoCheck)
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```

The item check enables to avoid the transition to another check state (called before the ItemChecked event). The solution is simple and sure.

To find it out I made a small test with different events:

When clicking:

1. MouseDown <------------- inhibited region
2. Click
3. MouseClick
4. MouseUp ------------->
5. ItemCheck (**outside** inhibited region)
6. ItemChecked

When double clicking:

1. MouseDown <------------- inhibited region
2. ItemSelectionChanged
3. SelectedIndexChanged
4. Click
5. MouseClick
6. MouseUp ------------->
7. MouseDown <------------- inhibited region
8. ItemCheck (**inside** inhibited region)
9. ItemActivate
10. DoubleClick
11. MouseDoubleClick
12. MouseUp ------------->