# Winforms ListView - Stop automatically checking when double clicking

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

How do I make a listview not automatically check an item when I double click it?

I can try hooking into the MouseDoubleClick event, and set the Checked property to false, but that feels like a bit of an hack. I also run a reasonably expensive calculation when an item is actually checked, and don't want this code to run on a double click. With the event hooking above, the ItemCheck & ItemChecked events are raised before the double click is handled.

Is there an elegent solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Elegant isn't typically the word that jumps to mind when you have to hack the way the native Windows control works, but that's what required here.  Do consider if you really want your control to behave differently from the listviews in any other program.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyListView : ListView {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Filter WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
        if (m.Msg != 0x203) base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is the least hacky way to do it.... this works, especially if you call the OnMouseDoubleClick method from WndProc when the message is hit. This bypasses the Check handling, while keeping the double click event which is what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Comment: This guy has a similar replacement, where the double click also continues to work:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hippietim/archive/2006/03/27/562256.aspx

Comment: Almost..   I want double click to work, just not check or uncheck the item when double clicked.   This stops all other messages.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to turn of the DoubleClick messages completely, but just turn off the autocheck behaviour. You can instead do the following:

```
public class NoDoubleClickAutoCheckListview : ListView
{
    private bool checkFromDoubleClick = false;

    protected override void OnItemCheck(ItemCheckEventArgs ice)
    {
        if (this.checkFromDoubleClick)
        {
            ice.NewValue = ice.CurrentValue;
            this.checkFromDoubleClick = false;
        }
        else
            base.OnItemCheck(ice);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Is this a double-click?
        if ((e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) && (e.Clicks > 1)) {
            this.checkFromDoubleClick = true;
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.checkFromDoubleClick = false;
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: great, covers exactly my needs and works fine for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and this is how I handled it.
Basically if the item is checked while the cursor's x coordinate is greater than the checkbox's x coordinate, then I cancel the check (because it means the check was called when the user double clicked the item).

The margin of error with the number 22 is only if the user double clicks right after the check box (very hard to do).

**NOTE:** My code assumes the user will not double click the checkbox (either the user double clicks the item or single clicks the checkbox)

Sorry code is in VB :)

```
Private Sub lvComboLists_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles lvComboLists.ItemCheck
    Dim i As Integer = CType(sender, ListView).PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X
    If i > 22 Then
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to diferentiate between user actions and program actions for the ItemCheck event. I did that by adding a "MyDoing" boolean variable on the form in order to let program-originated checking pass.

Comment: I've found this other solution that seems even simpler (less messy): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406887/only-change-a-listviewitems-checked-state-if-the-checkbox-is-clicked

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution suggested as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1407230/3417858) for similar question was just ok for my use:

```cs
private bool inhibitAutoCheck;

private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    inhibitAutoCheck = true;
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    inhibitAutoCheck = false;
}

private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    if (inhibitAutoCheck)
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a much simpler method of just resetting the checkbox's value to the original state by changing it to the opposite of what it currently is:

```
    Private Sub lst_Images_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lst_Images.DoubleClick
        Dim fIndex As Integer = Me.lst_Images.SelectedIndices(0)
        ' Undo the changing of the checkbox's state by the double click event. 
        lst_Images.Items(fIndex).Checked = Not lst_Images.Items(fIndex).Checked

        ' Call the viewer form
        Dim fViewer As New Image_Edit(fIndex)
        fViewer.ShowDialog()
        fViewer.Dispose()
End Sub
```