# How to disable double click event in ListView object?

Tags: c#, listview, event-handling

I am trying to disable DoubleClick event on all my ListView objects. My listview is a checked type and when double click the objects besides the check box will make the item to check. How to avoid this?

```
lvPC.DoubleClick -= new EventHandler(ListView_DoubleClick);
lvWeb.DoubleClick -= new EventHandler(ListView_DoubleClick);
lvSerialCode.DoubleClick -= new EventHandler(ListView_DoubleClick);

private void ListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how can you avoid having to type the first 3 lines of code or are you saying the current code doesn't work?

Comment: @Jason Down: The code I have used doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no easy "non-hackish" way to do this with the standard listview control by the looks of it (the click event fires before the double click event fire I believe). You are likely better off creating your own listview control. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897071/winforms-listview-stop-automatically-checking-when-double-clicking

Comment: @Jason Down, I have looked at it but when I am creating this class then it doesn't help, talking about the accepted answer, there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps changing the event setup code as follows might help:

```
lvPC.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(ListView_DoubleClick);
lvWeb.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(ListView_DoubleClick);
lvSerialCode.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(ListView_DoubleClick);
```

Comment: But then we are adding an event handler since of += sign. I want it to be removed.